# Custom Redirect URI for Meteor Accounts

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

I'm attempting to extend Meteor Accounts for [Edmodo](https://developers.edmodo.com/edmodo-connect/docs/#connecting-your-application) and believe that I have it set up at these repos: [accounts-edmodo](https://github.com/merlinpatt/accounts-edmodo) and [edmodo](https://github.com/merlinpatt/edmodo)

The issue is that I would like to have it set up for a custom redirect URI, yet this does not seem to be working. I think the issue is that the accounts system expects a specific redirect URI to trigger the [edmodo_server.js](https://github.com/merlinpatt/edmodo/blob/master/edmodo_server.js) code.

Any suggestions? I'm thinking that I'll need to use Iron Router somehow to do this. Or am I way off base in how the [edmodo_server.js](https://github.com/merlinpatt/edmodo/blob/master/edmodo_server.js) code is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

After another few hours, I discovered that all I had to do was add this to my `lib/routes.js` file:

```
Router.route('/custom/redirect/uri/path', function() {
  this.redirect('/_oauth/edmodo?close&code=' + this.params.query.code);
});
```

Though, this still seems to be missing something as now my server logs the following errors:

```
(oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
(oauth_server.js:398) Error in OAuth Server: Match error: Expected string, got undefined
```

So if anyone has a fix for the above errors and would like to edit this answer, please do so. Thank you.